# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible {vgg_classifier = model.fit}

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

```
vgg_classifier = model.fit(train_data_gen,
                           steps_per_epoch=(total_train//batch_size),
                           epochs = 5,
                           validation_data=val_data_gen,
                           validation_steps=(total_validation//batch_size),
                           batch_size = batch_size,
                           verbose = 1)
#start our training process
```

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible?
how can i fix this?

how can i fix this problem below?
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Comment: share your model and input please, there seems to be a missmatch

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your train and validation data shapes.